# Using Pinterest Marketing api to fetch all entities?

Tags: pinterest

Is there an edge that would allow fetching all the campaigns, adgroups, etc., of a given advertiser? In researching this I see these:

```
GET /ads/v3/campaigns/{campaign}/
GET /ads/v3/adgroups/{adgroup}/
...
```

which return only single entities. I also found that there is an async report that returns entities in batch:

```
advertisers/<advertiser ID>/entities/batch/
```

Is this the best way to accomplish this? If so, the doc says it only supports campaigns right now, is that still the case?

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the api meets our needs. I don't have an approved app yet otherwise I'd experiment programmatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to waste your time folks, I've since found more and better doc and discovered that there is this:

```
/ads/v3/advertisers/{advertiser}/campaigns/
```

Here is a link to the doc for your own reference:

```
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/#operation/ads_v3_get_advertiser_campaigns_handler_GET
```